# Getting 3D image from 2D image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing a project in Matlab on Image processing

Is there any possibility of getting 3d image from 2d image?

Comment: Without a more descriptive question I doubt anyone can give you a good answer about this. The short one is no because the definition of a 2D image is one without a 3rd dimension of data. But if you could scan the image based on colors or something you might be able to "create" a 3d image out of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's no need to say "help me" in your question (in fact, it's probably counter-productive). Helping people is the whole reason a lot of people are here. :-) Good luck with your question.

Comment: Do you mean, some way of extracting depth from a single 2d image?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple images of the same object and the position of the camera when the picure was taken, then it is possible, but still not easy. You can find two such datasets and links to relevant articles here:  http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/

Answer (score 0):

a 3d image would be a projection from 4d (and to show one of those you've got to project down to 2d) and most images that can be displayed on computer or in a picture frame are 2d projections of 3d objects due to this projection which in fact selects a slice of the higher dimensional space it doesn't contain the information needed to invert that projection and get back to 3d from a 2d image

but if you have sufficient sampling of the space it is possible to reconstruct a 3d object from 2d images of it but i don't know of any simple ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without supporting data such as multiple 2D images describing the same 3D object.  You then need to figure out the perspectives from which each image was taken, reconcile those into real space, and generate your points using a method such as intersection of stereo lines through each image plane onto the same physical coordinate.

You can also attempt a superpixel approach by exploiting lighting data within a single image, though these methods aren't as accurate.

This is a big field.

Answer (score 0):

The [Radon transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) is used in tomography applications to reconstruct 3D representations (i.e.images) from many 2D projections of the 3D "scene". This transform and its inverse are present in the image processing toolbox of Matlab. You might want to have a look at it.

Hope this helps.

A.