# How to create 3D model using stack of 2D images

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d-reconstruction

I used the below code to create the 3D model using multiple 2D images.
[How to create a 3D image with series of 2D Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699525/how-to-create-a-3d-image-with-series-of-2d-image)

I used python 3.9 for this. I uploaded photos below with description.

I have many images of cells, one shown here as example[inner white part is the cell and I want to ignore the outside black part[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTfAz.png)

After running this code, I am getting the following result as shown in image [only the bands of color is visible and there is no visibility of light white color cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SA4c.png).

I want to see these cells in 3D model with proper clariy.

Can someone help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which function do you use to display the 3d image? Maybe it is considered as a color image instead of a 3d image...

Comment: I have black and white image, little white spot in full dark background. I am using open3d function to open the .ply file generated by above program. But I do not know why color shades are coming in the output.

Comment: import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

# Read .ply file
input_file = "test.ply"
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file) # Read the point cloud

# Visualize the point cloud within open3d
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd]) 

# Convert open3d format to numpy array
# Here, you have the point cloud in numpy format. 
point_cloud_in_numpy = np.asarray(pcd.points)